# CakePhp Auth session data: dot notation not working

Tags: php, session, cakephp, authentication

If I add the following code to a controller action and visit it:

```
debug($this->Session->read('Auth.User'));
```

If see the following printed:

```
array(
    'User' => array(
        'password' => '*****',
        'username' => 'admin'
    )
)
```

But if I try and access the 'username' using dot notation:

```
debug($this->Session->read('Auth.User.username'));
```

It returns null.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You are missing to login into site....make sure you are logged in with valid username and password..

Comment: try this debug($this->Session->read('Auth.User.User.username'));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this    `debug($this->Session->read('Auth.User.User.username'));`

Comment: Any idea why there is no id in the Auth.User session array? It's present in the db table as the primary key :?

Comment: please try this  $userid =$this->Auth->user('id'); or $userId = $this->Session->read('User.id');

Comment: Both $this->Auth->user and $this->Session->read('User') debug as null.

Comment: Ah I missed this part :) :

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html

'Be sure to manually add the new User id to the array passed to the login method. Otherwise you won’t have the user id available'